# lexer rule for string that doesnt include the "s

Tags: antlr4

Simple question but I cant work it out, Antlr4

I have

```
STRING: '"' .*? '"';
```

problem is that I end up with the quotes in the extracted value. I can of course strip them myself in my visitor, but that seems wrong